# Synchronisation of Bow/Bower example in java oracle tutorial with reentrant lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock, locks

The code given here on  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html gives synchronisation of bow and bower with lock objects , so that it can avoid deadlock.

here is the code

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.Random;

public class Safelock {
static class Friend {
    private final String name;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
        Boolean myLock = false;
        Boolean yourLock = false;
        try {
            myLock = lock.tryLock();
            yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
        } finally {
            if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
                if (myLock) {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                if (yourLock) {
                    bower.lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
        return myLock && yourLock;
    }

    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        if (impendingBow(bower)) {
            try {
                System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                    + " bowed to me!%n", 
                    this.name, bower.getName());
                bower.bowBack(this);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
                bower.lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.format("%s: %s started"
                + " to bow to me, but saw that"
                + " I was already bowing to"
                + " him.%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has" +
            " bowed back to me!%n",
            this.name, bower.getName());
    }
}

static class BowLoop implements Runnable {
    private Friend bower;
    private Friend bowee;

    public BowLoop(Friend bower, Friend bowee) {
        this.bower = bower;
        this.bowee = bowee;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (;;) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            bowee.bow(bower);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Friend alphonse =
        new Friend("Alphonse");
    final Friend gaston =
        new Friend("Gaston");
    new Thread(new BowLoop(alphonse, gaston)).start();
    new Thread(new BowLoop(gaston, alphonse)).start();
}
```

}

My Question is - supposedly thread 1 - alphanso thread and thread 2 - gaston thread executes at same pace all the time. So they will call impendingBow() together. Both of them tries to acquire lock of itself and another object and if any of the lock is not available then they release the acquired lock if any. 
Now if both threads are executing lines in same rate , So alphanso thread will be able to get lock of itself and so will gaston but both will fail to get lock of other as they have been acquired by themselves .
Now according to code both of them will free their own lock ( as they could not get other's lock.) and return false from impendingBow() and both will print

```
else {
        System.out.format("%s: %s started"
            + " to bow to me, but saw that"
            + " I was already bowing to"
            + " him.%n",
            this.name, bower.getName());
    }
```

and then again the same thing.
 Wont this process run indefinitely with no one bowing to each other ever?

Comment: Yes. That is called a livelock. In pactice, however, this is somewhat unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `BowLoop` has infinite loop with a random delay (`Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));`) which prevents scenario that you described. It is a common practice to use random delay before reattempting to get locks after release in case of "collisions".

Comment: "*Class `BowLoop` has infinite loop with a random delay (`Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));`) which prevents scenario that you described*" - While this is true in practice, it is unproveable that this will indeed terminate.

Comment: @Turing85 it will not terminate because loop is infinite. But it will not face situation when they both try to acquire locks again in the same time. (Like in collision recovery procedure in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection)

Comment: For the extreme unlikely case that both threads generate the same random sequence and both threads run in perfect sync, it will not terminate. Thus, I said that it does not proveable terminate.

Comment: @Turing85 one needs to be very lucky to have `Random` generate the same int in both threads always. Two threads might fall into collision upon start and that is OK, they will wait for random periods. But possibility of falling into collisions with random delays on each iteration is ignorable